Inputting the command python returns to fix error but then returns another
Whenever I run code that involves the tensorflow library in python with VSC, it returns this:
You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0.
I then input the command given (in both the cmd and terminal) and an error is returned saying the command isn't recognised.
When I echo the command it says it is set to 0 as specified, but still it isn't recognised in my python file. I've tried numerous sources but can't seem to find any solutions

do you use Windows? On Linux you could run it in console/terminal/bash in one line TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0 python script.py and it will set it before starting script.py. Or you have to set TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0 in system before you run any script or IDE.
